# Classical & Abstract Harmonic Analysis

Tags: research

My main question is about decision on research in math. 
What is the main differences between Classical and abstract Harmonic analysis?? Real Variables,Fourier Series, Functional analysis and General topology are they enough for correct decision on research in Classical Harmonic analysis (not abstract)? My education especially focused on those fields of math. Or what else, can someone show me correct direction about "research decision"?

Comment: follow your heart ... Most mathematics requires the use of your mind ... really beautiful mathematics will touch your heart too ... Read the book http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.167.5285&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit it was not opened can you say its name I can search thanks...

Comment: Do a Google search on "Proofs from the book" ... click the second one on the list.

Comment: Not "shaw" , show. I saw this twice. I hear  a female mathematician of ukraine used approximation theory (like fourier series) to prove it's optimal in 24 dimensional shere-packing problem, Terence Tao would know  all your category.